# Local database docker to AWS database in VPN

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, docker, containers, database-link

i'm a beginner to Docker, hope everyone can help, much appreciated.

I downloaded a docker image from my company repository and i managed to create a container in my local machine from the image, let's named it mydb. It is created through command below:
***docker run --name mydb -p 1521:1521 -d mycompany.com:5000/docker-db:20.0.04***

I am able to access the database with following connection string through my sqldqveloper : **system/abc123@127.0.0.1:1521/ORCL**

Our company have a database server in AWS, let's name it awsdb. I can access it after vpn login.
I am able to access the database with following connection string in sqldqveloper :
**system/abc123@awsdb.amazonaws.com:1521/awsdb**

Question:
How can i create a database link in mydb to awsdb with database link "my_dblink"? eg. select sysdate from dual@my_dblink.

I try with following command:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK my_dblink
CONNECT TO system
IDENTIFIED BY abc123
USING 'awsdb.amazonaws.com:1521/awsdb';
```

but it return error ORA-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable.

I tried remove the container and recreated it by set the net=host:
***docker run --name mydb -p 1521:1521 -d --net=host mycompany.com:5000/docker-db:20.0.04***
then now i can't even connect is with **system/abc123@127.0.0.1:1521/ORCL**
error ORA-12541 returned: no listener.

How can i open the connection between internal docker to AWS database server? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do believe you need to understand what you are trying to accomplish.
When you create a database link between two databases, **the main requirement you must fulfil is to have network connectivity between both of them in the ports you are using**. As one of them is stored in public cloud, at least you would need:

- A network connection between the network where the docker is installed and the public cloud in `AWS`.
- But, as your docker is installed in your local laptop, the `AWS` should be opened to Internet, something that it is a security issue and probably it is not enabled.
- Moreover, you would need Firewall rules in all the ports you might need to use in this connectivity.

As you are using a `VPN` login that allows you to access the `AWS Cloud` resources because you are connecting through it ( probably using `Active Directory` and/or a `certificate`, perhaps even using `SSO federation` between your `AD` in your company and the resources in `AWS` ), the database can't connect using that.

Summarizing, that is not possible, and if I were someone in Security I would never allow it. The only option for you would be to create a `docker` with the database in `AWS` and then create the database link there.